# Automatically send a file from a server to an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, networking

What would be the best way to send a file from a server (e.g. php server) to an Android app. In other words, when a file is ready to be sent (e.g. is placed on a php server), this file gets automatically transferred to the Android app.

Could that be done in Volley or Retrofit or would you recommend a different solution?

Comment: Servers cannot sent files to whatever. A client can request a server to send a file.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes things clearer.